# Ethereum EIP-1559 compatible Web3 raw transaction structure

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm using an *EIP-1559* compatible Web3 package, and I am trying to find a structure for a raw signed transaction that uses `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` instead of `gasPrice`.

Just to clarify what I'm asking, here is what I was using before London fork (pre EIP-1559) to decipher raw signed transactions (now considered legacy):

```
class Transaction(rlp.Serializable):
    fields = [
        ("nonce", big_endian_int),
        ("gas_price", big_endian_int),
        ("gas", big_endian_int),
        ("to", Binary.fixed_length(20, allow_empty=True)),
        ("value", big_endian_int),
        ("data", binary),
        ("v", big_endian_int),
        ("r", big_endian_int),
        ("s", big_endian_int),
    ]
```

Now, when I sign transactions that use `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` fields, what will their resulting binary raw structure look like?